# How to work around Out of bounds nanosecond

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
 LastLogin                         LastPurchased              
2018-08-21 00:28:04.081677         0001-01-01 00:00:00
2018-08-21 00:28:58.209522         2018-08-20 00:28:58.209522
```

I need difference in days `(df[LastLogin] - df['LastPurchased']).dt.days` but there are some `'0001-01-01 00:00:00'` in `LastPurchased`. Anything I try to do to change `1-01-01` to a date within the Panda bounds results in `Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:00:00`. Is there any other ways?

```
     LastLogin                         LastPurchased              Days
2018-08-21 00:28:04.081677         1999-01-01 00:00:00            6935
2018-08-21 00:28:58.209522         2018-08-20 00:28:58.209522      1
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `errors='coerce'` in the call to `to_datetime`? That will replace it with 'pd.NaT' which is the datetime equivalent of NaN. You can also set it to `ignore`, but that will likely cause other problems

Comment: I have tried that and it does not work (for some reason)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pandas requires that the year in your datetime be greater than 1677 and less than 2622 (approximately - see [pandas/_libs/tslibs/src/datetime/np_datetime.c](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/tslibs/src/datetime/np_datetime.c) for the exact bounds).  Otherwise, the given date is outside the range that can be represented by nanosecond-resolution 64-bit integers:

```
>>> pd.Timestamp.max
Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')
>>> pd.Timestamp.min
Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225')
>>> pd.Timestamp.max - pd.Timestamp.min
datetime.timedelta(213503, 84873, 709550)
```

It's up to you how you want to handle this.  Consider what you are ultimately trying to *indicate* by subtracting the date 0001-01-01.  I'll assume that means a user has logged in but never purchased.

To coerce `LastPurchased` to either a valid Pandas Timestamp or `pd.NaT` ("not a time"), you can use

```
df['LastPurchased'] = pd.to_datetime(df['LastPurchased'], errors='coerce')
```

This will give `NaT` as the difference in those spots:

```
>>> pd.Timestamp(2018, 1, 1) - pd.NaT
NaT
```

Which you can use as a "sentinel" and check for with `pd.isnat()`.