# Out of bound timestamps in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I need to rewrite some sql code to python, and my problem is necessity of calculation differences in days:
[image]
As you can see, for cases with final_pmt_date ‘9999-12-31’, the dates subtracted easily.

But in pandas there is limit for datetime64 type, so I get exception:
[image]

All answers I saw were about converting this dates into NaN (with ‘coerce’ keyword). But I need to calculate number of days for such datetimes also.

Thank you in advance

Comment: if you want to make life easier for people trying to come up with a solution, provide example data / code as text, not image ;-)

Comment: for reference, related: [How to work around Out of bounds nanosecond](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54202896/10197418)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A date like `9999-12-31` is [out of range for pandas datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations).

Using [vanilla Python datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.MAXYEAR) might be an alternative here, e.g. like

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "open": ["2021-12-27 00:00:00.000", "2019-03-06 00:00:00.000"],
        "close": ["9999-12-31 00:00:00.000", "2022-04-06 00:00:00.000"],
    }
)

df["delta"] = df.apply(
    (
        lambda row: datetime.fromisoformat(row["close"])
        - datetime.fromisoformat(row["open"]),
    ),
    axis=1,
)

df
                      open                    close                  delta
0  2021-12-27 00:00:00.000  9999-12-31 00:00:00.000  2913908 days, 0:00:00
1  2019-03-06 00:00:00.000  2022-04-06 00:00:00.000     1127 days 00:00:00
```

However note that you'll have to use an `apply` which is not very efficient compared to the "vectorized" pandas datetime methods. Maybe using `NaT` as an "invalid-value-identfier" *is* an option after all?

Comment: Thank you very much! How can I convert this object to difference in days ? If I use only .days, I will calculate inaccurate as hours and minutes can be (I expect float number of days)

Comment: Find solution:  td.total_seconds() / timedelta (days=1).total_seconds()

Comment: @ЛюбовьПономарева since you have a timedelta column, you can use e.g. `df["delta"].dt.total_seconds()/86400` to get fractional days. If you want just days, you could convert to int.